# CMake ExternalProject_Add folders with prefixes in the build folder

Tags: c++, cmake

I install the libraries into **build/install/libraryname** folder.
I get all the files I need.
But in additional to these files the build folder contains **cgal_dependencies-prefix** folder that is almost empty folder with a few .cmake files.

What does this folder do and why it exists?

```
ExternalProject_Add(cgal_dependencies
  URL https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/releases/download/v5.4.1/CGAL-5.4.1-win64-auxiliary-libraries-gmp-mpfr.zip
  CMAKE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
    #-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install"
  SOURCE_DIR   "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cgal_dependencies"
    #INSTALL_DIR   "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/install"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND "" #do not configure
  BUILD_COMMAND "" #do not buld
  INSTALL_COMMAND "" #installer for now is empty
)
```

Another question is about arguments inside ExternalProject_Add function.
What is the difference between:

1. SOURCE_DIR
2. INSTALL_DIR
3. CMAKE_ARGS     -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH

This is the folder structure:
[image]

Comment: There is extenside documentation that explains it. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html . Is there something unclear to you in the documentation?

Comment: I really do not understand **INSTALL_DIR**  and **CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH** I am using header only libraries

Comment: What specifically you do not understand? `INSTALL_DIR` is a placeholder, as the documentation explains, `CMAKE_ARGS` are passed to cmake, as documentation explains. About `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` you can read https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html?highlight=cmake_install_prefix here.